# Calculate percentage of group using Group By SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a set of data that contains multiple groups of data(Vehicle_Code), each item(PK: Cusip_Sedol) in the group has a certain code(GIC_Code) that is not unique. I am trying to find the percentage of each code(GIC_Code) within each group(Vehicle_Name) of data. 
Here is my SQL Select statement thus far:

```
SELECT H.vehicle_code, 
       G.group_name, 
       Count(D.cusip_sedol) AS Total 
FROM   tbltrading_holdings AS H 
INNER JOIN tbltrading_stocks_data_stocks AS D 
        ON H.cusip_sedol = D.cusip_sedol 
LEFT JOIN tbltrading_gic AS G 
       ON D.gic_code = G.gic_code 
WHERE  vehicle_code IN (SELECT vehicle_code 
                        FROM   tbltrading_vehicles 
                        WHERE  vehicle_name LIKE 'J%') 
  AND D.gic_code IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY H.vehicle_code, 
          G.group_name 
ORDER  BY vehicle_code
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a sample data set including table structure so that people can set up a little test environment to help you out faster and more specific.

Comment: To provide the `vehicle_name` each `gic_code` is associated with, you have to do a real join, not an `IN` (which is effectively an `EXISTS`). However, is it possible for the same `gic_code` to join up to different `vehicle_name` values? (Since there is an intermediate `vehicle_code` that joins them?)

Comment: Each Vehicle has multiple cusip_sedols and each cusip_sedol has one GIC code. Each GIC code is associated with multiple cusip_sedols, and each cusip_sedol is associated with multiple vehicles

Comment: @NickDauphin You didn't actually answer my question...

Comment: @ErikE Yes, the same GIC code can pair up with multiple vehicle values. However, GIC code is not a property of a vehicle, it is a property of the cusip_sedol.

Comment: @NickDauphin Then what does "gic code per vehicle name" mean any more then, since a gic_code can pair with many vehicle names?

Comment: @ErikE each cusip_sedol is a stock and the gic_code is the industry of the company. Each Vehicle is a portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   H.vehicle_code,
   G.group_name,
   VehicleTotal = Count(D.cusip_sedol) OVER (PARTITION BY H.vehicle_code, G.group_name),
   d.gic_code,
   gic_codePercentPerVehicleName =
      Count(d.gic_code) OVER () * 1.0 / Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY V.vehicle_name),
   gic_codePercentPerVehicleName2 =
      Count(d.gic_code) * 1.0 / Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY V.vehicle_name)
FROM
   dbo.tbltrading_holdings H
   INNER JOIN tbltrading_stocks_data_stocks D
      ON H.cusip_sedol = D.cusip_sedol
   LEFT JOIN dbo.tbltrading_gic G
      ON D.gic_code = G.gic_code
   INNER JOIN dbo.tbltrading_vehicles V
      ON H.vehicle_code = V.vehicle_code
      AND v.vehicle_name LIKE 'J%'
WHERE
   D.gic_code IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
   H.vehicle_code,
   D.gic_code,
   G.group_name,
   V.vehicle_name
ORDER BY
   H.vehicle_code
;
```

There are some unknowns here that have forced me to make certain assumptions. You can see that I've come up with two different interpretations about what "gic code per vehicle name" could mean.

For starters, to provide the `vehicle_name` each `gic_code` is associated with, we have to do a real join, not an `IN` (which is effectively an `EXISTS`). However, is it possible for the same `gic_code` to join up to different `vehicle_name` values? (Since there is an intermediate `vehicle_code` that joins them?) I'm assuming that it's *not* possible for this to happen, and if it actually is, the query will give unuseful results, and you'll have to formulate better what exactly you're looking for before we can help you more.

Next, the results are all muddied by the fact that you're selecting so many columns, which forces them to be part of the `GROUP BY`. But once you do that, then all the windowing functions have to include partitions to "break" them out of the grouping. This query may run slowly, as it's being made to do a lot at once, which could result in many scans of the table. The way things are now, for each particular `gic_code`, you'll get many rows with the same value, because the query has to expose the (multiple) `vehicle_code` and `group_name` combinations for each one. Is that really what you want?

You might get better results if you removed some of the displayed columns, as this would let you remove at least some of the `PARTITION BY` expressions.

Last, I'm not sure I even got the partitions correct. Only you know the cardinality of each column in relation to the joins to other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close.  Is counting the Sedol working for you?  If so then just divide that by the count of the group name for your percentage:

```
SELECT H.vehicle_code, 
       G.group_name, 
       cast(Count(DISTINCT D.cusip_sedol) as DECIMAL)/cast(count(DISTINCT G.group_name) as DECIMAL) AS Total --add this second part
FROM   tbltrading_holdings AS H 
INNER JOIN tbltrading_stocks_data_stocks AS D 
        ON H.cusip_sedol = D.cusip_sedol 
LEFT JOIN tbltrading_gic AS G 
       ON D.gic_code = G.gic_code 
WHERE  vehicle_code IN (SELECT vehicle_code 
                        FROM   tbltrading_vehicles 
                        WHERE  vehicle_name LIKE 'J%') 
  AND D.gic_code IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY H.vehicle_code, 
          G.group_name 
ORDER  BY vehicle_code
```

Comment: When I do that I get totals of 1.

Comment: Got it, you just need to add distinct to both Counts to make sure you are only counting that unique pairing

Comment: Don't use `float`, it's an inexact data type. It's not that you'll get such a wrong answer here, but that `float` is inherently bad for anything but statistical purposes and advanced math, or situations where loss of precision is *completely understood*, and *desired*, because of the preservation of *scale*. Start using `decimal` everywhere in your coding and SQL tables, etc., until you learn a case where `float` is truly demanded. I promise you'll be a more advanced developer doing this.

Comment: Great advice thanks!  [Reading this now](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx) 38 digits is more than sufficient here

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the total over all the rows . . . and you can get this using window functions.  So, change the select to:

```
SELECT H.vehicle_code, 
       G.group_name, 
       Count(D.cusip_sedol) AS Total,
       Count(D.Cusip_sedol)*1.0 / Sum(Count(D.Cusip_sedol)) Over () as p_total
. . .
```

Note that the `*1.0` is there just to prevent integer division.

Comment: This returns the percentage of each GIC_code for each vehicle over all the vehicles. I am looking for the percentage of each GIC code for it's respective vehicle.

Comment: @NickDauphin That is why you should always include sample data and expected output so we know what you need.